# How to merge back the encrypted folder back to main drive

Tags: macos, folders

Have one encrypted folder and have erased the content of it. But not getting any option to merge the space back to the main partition.

[image: Protected.dmg is the encrypted folder and in the left frame we can see Disk Image] This comes after we enter the password or rather mount the encrypted drive.
[image: The Disk images are listed, here only one.]
As we can see that the Disk Image is of 10GB. I want this space to merge with other drive: Macintosh.

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypted folder": is this a folder in Finder, a DMG file, a partition on your hard drive? Also where are you looking for an option to merge, in which application? Adding a screenshot so others can see what you are looking at might help as well.

Comment: I have updated the question with images. Trying to do using Disk Utility. the process to create the folder/Protected.dmg file was: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/encrypt-mac-folder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a disk image, which is basically just a file. You haven't partitioned your Macintosh disk, as can be seen if you select Macintosh in Disk Utility.

To remove the disk image, unmount the disk image using the Eject button next to Disk Image, then delete the file using Finder. This will reclaim the space on your Macintosh drive in the same way deleting any other file will.